# MAP_HUGE_1GB and MAP_HUGE_2MB missing?

Tags: c++, g++, centos7, mmap, huge-pages

I am on CentOS 7 with kernel version 3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64.

When I tried to use `MAP_HUGE_1GB` and `MAP_HUGE_2MB` flags, g++-9.3.1 complained:

```
error: ‘MAP_HUGE_1GB’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘MAP_HUGETLB’?
```

Then, I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59537934/map-hugetlb-undefined), the answer suggested that I need to "`#define _GNU_SOURCE` before `#include <sys/mman.h>` because this is a nonstandard flag".

However, defining `_GNU_SOURCE` causes `warning: "_GNU_SOURCE" redefined` but g++ still complains those 2 flags aren't declared.

Then, I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670581/why-is-gnu-source-defined-by-default-and-how-to-turn-it-off), and it suggests that `_GNU_SOURCE` defined as `libstdc++` is used.

Now, I am confused how to use `MAP_HUGE_1GB` and `MAP_HUGE_2MB` flags.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glibc doesn't define either `MAP_HUGE_1GB` or `MAP_HUGE_2MB` in any of its headers. If you have the `kernel-headers` package installed, you can get those constants by doing `#include <linux/mman.h>`. This isn't really ideal, though, so I'm not sure why glibc doesn't give you a better way to get them.